# Scan multiple barcodes with ZXing

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am currently trying to get ZXing to scan some barcodes. It's doing that job fine so far (via intent).

Now I would like to make it decode multiple barcodes at once (they are placed beneath each other) without having to scan each barcode individually.

Is this even possible via intent? If not, a short example of how to do it the other way would be appreciated :)

I've so far only found a pretty old thread where a user requested this feature and some developers seem to have integrated it. However, I am unable to find any tutorial explaining the utilization.

The thread can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=183).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible by Intent, but it is certainly possible within the project. You would have to write your own scanning component, then use the core library's support (which you've found) to find multiple barcodes and do something with them.

Comment: It's neither really the answer that I had hoped for nor do you provide any tutorial on how to do so... However, seeing that nobody else has any superior ideas, I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: Happy to help more on the discussion group. I don't want to repeat what you already know. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/zxing   The essence is to just use `MultipleBarcodeReader` as a wrapper on whatever `Reader` you are currently using. That's about it.