# Multiple Barcode Scanner in Android

Tags: android, barcode

I want my project to scan multiple barcodes in one go. E.g. there are nine barcodes placed line by line. I am able to scan one barcode at a time with this tutorial https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-barcode-and-qr-scanner-example/ using ZXING. How do I scan multiple barcodes in one go?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scan multiple barcodes with ZXing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628373/scan-multiple-barcodes-with-zxing)

Comment: @fiddler I checked that question but it was not answered properly. There is no code or any example for explanation. If you can provide any example of code for doing this on that question then I will surely accept it as duplicated. Please, I need help.

Comment: You will probably need to get the source code of the library and manage this by yourself. The source code is well explained so this will not be so difficult to find a way to do so.
By the way, probably the best way to return result for this case is as an event.